# How to get a serial number of a Windows disk?

Tags: winapi, windows-7, ioctl

I'm trying to get a serial number of a disk, using IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER:

```
HANDLE h = CreateFile ("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", GENERIC_READ,
                        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,
                        OPEN_EXISTING,
                        FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, 0);
if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
  struct {
    USHORT Reserved;
    USHORT SerialNumberLength;
    UCHAR SerialNumber[252];
  } dsn;
  DWORD nr;   
  memset(&dsn, '\0', sizeof dsn);
  if ((DeviceIoControl(h, IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER,
                       NULL, 0, &dsn, sizeof(dsn), &nr, 0))) {
    printf("Serial number: %s\n", dsn.SerialNumber);
  } else {
    printf("No serial number, error %d.\n", (int)GetLastError());
  }
}
```

However, `GetLastError()` returns ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION.

The disk does exist, and it has a serial number, see this registry entry:

[image: disk with serial number in regedit]

How can I retrieve the serial number from C code without using the registry?

Comment: *If a USB device has a CSM-1 content security interface, a USB client driver can query for its serial number using this request.* the `ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION` is converted from `STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST` - mean that device simply not support this ioctl

Comment: @RbMm: Thank you for the insight. There is no USB device connected to this computer, so I still don't understand why I'm getting this error.

Comment: but device, to which you send `IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER` not handle this request. it return `STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST` error. win32 layer convert it to `ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION` and return false from `DeviceIoControl`. if serial exist on device (not all disk devices have it) - it can be got via `IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we can use [`IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff800830(v=vs.85).aspx) with [`StorageDeviceProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566996(v=vs.85).aspx) (*Indicates that the caller is querying for the device descriptor*, [`STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566971(v=vs.85).aspx))

and use `SerialNumberOffset` member of `STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR`

> Specifies the byte offset from the beginning of the structure to a
>   NULL-terminated ASCII string that contains the device's serial number.
>   If the device has no serial number, this member is zero.

code can look like this:

```
ULONG GetSerial(HANDLE hFile)
{
    static STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY spq = { StorageDeviceProperty, PropertyStandardQuery }; 

    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PSTR psz;
        PSTORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR psdd;
    };

    ULONG size = sizeof(STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR) + 0x100;

    ULONG dwError;

    do 
    {
        dwError = ERROR_NO_SYSTEM_RESOURCES;

        if (buf = LocalAlloc(0, size))
        {
            ULONG BytesReturned;

            if (DeviceIoControl(hFile, IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY, &spq, sizeof(spq), buf, size, &BytesReturned, 0))
            {
                if (psdd->Version >= sizeof(STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR))
                {
                    if (psdd->Size > size)
                    {
                        size = psdd->Size;
                        dwError = ERROR_MORE_DATA;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (psdd->SerialNumberOffset)
                        {
                            DbgPrint("SerialNumber = %s\n", psz + psdd->SerialNumberOffset);
                            dwError = NOERROR;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dwError = ERROR_NO_DATA;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dwError = ERROR_GEN_FAILURE;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                dwError = GetLastError();
            }

            LocalFree(buf);
        }
    } while (dwError == ERROR_MORE_DATA);

    return dwError;
}
```

also for open device we can use `CreateFileW (L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", 0, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);` - in place *dwDesiredAccess* we can use 0 because `IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY` defined as 
`CTL_CODE(IOCTL_STORAGE_BASE, 0x0500, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS)` - so `FILE_ANY_ACCESS` - accept any file access and `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` have sense only for file system devices (more general which use cache) - for disk devices - this is irrelevant

Comment: Yes, this code with IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY and SerialNumberOffset works with some minor modifications.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried different approaches and figured out that sending IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY doesn't work as expected for different USB devices in both User and Kernel mode code. For some USB mass storages it doesn't return serial number. I'd assume that there are 2 correct ways to do that:

- IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER (a few AV products do that?)
- create and send URB_CONTROL_DESCRIPTOR_REQUEST

Update 1.
I saw using IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER in the one file system mini-filter driver that was used like the following:

```
FltGetDiskDeviceObject( FltObjects->Volume, &pDevice );
        Irp = IoBuildDeviceIoControlRequest(
            IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER,
            Device,
...
        Irp = IoBuildDeviceIoControlRequest(
            IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER,
            Device,....
```

I haven't tested this yet in KernelMode code, unfortunately, but trying to make it works in user mode code shows that this IOCTL mostly
is not supported by different devices, maybe this IOCTL is reserved for the future as a standard way to get the serial number and will be
required by USB standards later?

Also, "wmic diskdrive get name, serialnumber" returns in my case for USB Mass Storage incorrect serial number = "E" the same result as we would use IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY.
So, the correct way to get the serial number of USB mass storage is creating a USB request block in KernelMode code and using DeviceIoControl to the hub driver in the UserMode code.

USBVIEW (UserMode code) gets serial number by sending IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX ioctl to the HUB driver which
returns USB_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX that contains USB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR. iSerialNumber member of USB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR is used later in the
IOCTL_USB_GET_DESCRIPTOR_FROM_NODE_CONNECTION ioctl request to the hub driver which finally gets serial number.

Another approach I see is maybe using some 3-rd party libraries like libusb to simplicate all these actions...

Update 2.
I took a look at USBSTOR disassembled code. USBSTOR_DeviceControl routine has the following code for the IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER

```
    ++v3->CurrentLocation;
    ++v3->Tail.Overlay.CurrentStackLocation;
    v8 = IofCallDriver(*(PDEVICE_OBJECT *)(v6 + 24), v3);
```

So, it passes the IRP down the stack to the usbhub driver as was expected. So maybe this functionlaty is expected to be realized in
the usbhub driver sometime ? That would be great as for me...

Comment: As indicated in the question, IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_MEDIA_SERIAL_NUMBER didn't work for me.

Comment: @pts thanks, you are right. I rechecked this and updated my answer.